# Prove that $ Q=\{v \in V: \left \langle v,v \right \rangle_A =0 \} \ $ is a real subspace of $ \ V \ $

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear space $ \ V=\mathbb{C}^2 \ $ and the Hermitian matrix  $ \ A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 & -i \\ 2 & i & 3 \end{bmatrix} \ $ with

$$ \ \left \langle X,Y \right \rangle_A=X^*AY \ $$

Prove that $ \ Q=\{v \in V: \left \langle v,v \right \rangle_A =0 \} \ $ is a real subspace of $ \ V \ $

**Answer:**

Clearly, $ \left \langle 0,0 \right \rangle_A=0 \ $. Thus $ \ 0 \in Q \ $.

Next **how to show that**

$$ \left \langle a u+bv,\ au+bv \right \rangle_A \ \in Q, $$

where $ a, b \ $ are scalars ?

**I am unable right here.**

Help me out

Answer (score 1):

You should show that if $u, v \in Q$, then $au+bv \in Q$.

That is if $u^*Au=0$ and $v^*Av=0$, then $(au+bv)^*A(au+bv)=0.$

Try to prove that by expanding and using linearity property.

Notice that $A^*=A$, that is $A$ is hermitian,  hence $u^*Au=0 \implies Au=0$, this property is useful in proving the result.

Comment: $(au+bv)^*A(au+bv)=(au+bv)^*(aAu+bAv)$ right? can you continue the expansion?

Comment: yes now i can continue